# javascript: using an assignment statement where a conditional expression would normally be

Tags: javascript

I just came across a piece of javascript code which used an assignment statement in the place where a logical `&&` or logical `OR` expression would be used:

```javascript
var geo;

function getGeoLocation() {
    try {
        if ( !! navigator.geolocation ) {
            return navigator.geolocation;
        } else {
            return undefined;        
        }
    } catch(e) {
      return undefined;
    }
}


if (geo = getGeoLocation()) {  
 // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this is the statement I am interested in
  console.log('conditional expression was true/truthy');
}
```

My question is, from the perspective of the `if` statement, what is being returned when
`geo = getGeoLocation()` is evaluated?
Particularly what is it the result of? and what is the type?
is it

- Whatever the function `getGeoLocation()` returned?
  (in which the type would be truthy/falsy)
- is it the "result" of the assignment? i.e. whether or not something non-null was assigned?
  (in which case the "result" might be boolean, true/false?)
- or something else?

Comment: Yeah, the value returned by `geolocation()` would be used to test the `if` condition. For example `if (a = false) {console.log("abc")}
undefined` but `if (a = true) {console.log("abc")}
VM402:1 abc`

Comment: The "result" of an assignment is the value that was assigned. That is to say that the assignment operator returns the value that was assigned.That's why `a = b = c = "test"` works.

Comment: Just read the [documentation for the assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Assignment), which says clearly "The assignment operation evaluates to the assigned value" (in other words, the RHS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (geo = getGeoLocation()) {  
  // ...
}
```

> My question is, from the perspective of the if statement, what is being returned when
>   geo = getGeoLocation() is evaluated?

Here are the chronological steps of what will happen:

- `getGeoLocation()` will execute first
- assignment operation will happen next, where whatever `getGeolocation()` returns will be stored in `geo`

  - This will be either `undefined` or `navigator.geolocation`, if it exists.
- `geo` will then be evaluated (tested for [truthiness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)) as the
  condition to the `if` statement

The equivalent of that code is the following:

```
geo = getGeoLocation();
if (geo) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: thanks, your statement  `geo = getGeoLocation(); if (geo) {  // ... }` seems to me a useful way to think about it. this is pretty much the answer I was hoping for, thanks

Comment: no problem, glad to help if I can

Comment: I would recommend writing it this way, because it is more obvious months down the track. Imagine having some bug, glancing at the code and immediately changing it to `==` because, well, that's the more common pattern - then you've introduced another bug :p

Comment: @JaromandaX - When I learnt C, I was taught that if only one of the `==` operands is a variable to put it on the right. As in, `5 == x`, not `x == 5`, or `getGeoLocation()==geo`, not `geo==getGeoLocation()`. That way if you accidentally use `=` you find the bug immediately via a compilation error. But because C coders are cowboys I was also taught that a deliberate assignment in an if (or while, etc.) condition is perfectly acceptable and I do still do that in JS if it seems appropriate. Though in JS I generally use `===` and `!==` for comparisons, so that makes a single `=` stand out more.

Comment: Actually, this is somewhere between incorrect and misleading. An assignment simply evaluates to its RHS. For instance, if `geo` is a property, it might have a getter, but that getter will never be called when evaluating the `if` condition. Then you say *geo will then be coerced to a boolean*. This is also incorrect. It would be correct to say "if `geo` is truthy", which is distinctly different from being coerced to a boolean. For example, `{ valueOf: false}` is truthy, yet when coerced to a boolean is false.

Comment: You're absolutely right about the "coercion to boolean" part, it's fixed now. Not sure what you're indicating with the first part though, is there anything else that you think is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If navigator succeeds you get a geolocation object, which is truthy and if it fails you can see in the else part, the function is returning undefined which is falsy.

Answer (score -1):

It could return true or false, or perhaps 1 or 0.

Simply, any value that is not 0 or false evaluates as true, we can do things like:

```
if (true)
    always do this
if (false)
    never do this
```

Or

```
// loop will break when v = 0
var v = 10
while (v) {
    if (v)
        do something...
    v--;
}
```

Comment: any object that is not 0, false, undefined or null.

Comment: Contrary to the comment in your code, that while loop will never end.

Comment: I guess instead of "return" you mean "evaluate to". Anyway, it doesn't "return true or false", it **evaluates** to a truthy or falsy value.